# Why no argument value was captured?

Tags: junit, mockito

When I invoke verify using captor, no argument value was captured. But 
if I invoke verify using captor at the beginning, the captor will get all values. Who can tell me why ?

```
public class AuthenticatorApplicationTest {
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> captor;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
     public void testAuthenticate() {
        AuthenticatorInterface authenticatorMock;
        CookBook1.AuthenticatorApplication authenticator;
        String username = "JavaCodeGeeks";
        String passwd = "unsafePassword";

        authenticatorMock = Mockito.mock(AuthenticatorInterface.class);
        authenticator = new CookBook1.AuthenticatorApplication(authenticatorMock);
        Mockito.when(authenticatorMock.authenticateUser(username, passwd)).thenReturn(false);
        boolean actual = authenticator.authenticate(username, passwd);

        Mockito.verify(authenticatorMock, Mockito.times(1)).authenticateUser(username, passwd);
        Mockito.verify(authenticatorMock, Mockito.atMost(1)).authenticateUser(captor.capture(), eq(passwd));
        Mockito.verify(authenticatorMock, Mockito.atLeast(1)).authenticateUser(username, passwd);
        Mockito.verify(authenticatorMock, Mockito.atMost(1)).authenticateUser(username, passwd);
        Mockito.verify(authenticatorMock, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).authenticateUser(username, passwd);


        System.out.println(captor.getAllValues());
        //Assert.assertEquals("xxx", captor.getValue(), "JavaCodeGeeks");
        //Assert.assertFalse(actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does not work?

Comment: Which version of Mockito are you using?

Comment: Mockito.verify(authenticatorMock, Mockito.atMost(1)).authenticateUser(captor.capture(), eq(passwd));

Comment: mockito version is  2.11.0